# Laravel Relationships - access input from other table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I cant get this working. This should be easy, but I cant figure out how to access a users gamer tag from different table using relationships.

Here is my User.php Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'gamertag', 'slug', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];


    // A user has many messages (Chat)
    public function chat () {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Chat');
    }
}
```

Here is my Chat.php Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Chat extends Model {


    protected $table = "chat";


    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'message', 'user_id'
    ];


    // A Chat (or message) belong to a user
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }


}
```

And this is how I;m retrieving the messages:

```
class HomeController extends Controller {


    public function index () {

        $messages = Chat::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

        return view('layouts.index', compact('messages'));
    }

}
```

Why Im I having trouble getting the gamer tag to display?

```
@foreach($messages as $message)
     <a class="author">{{ $message->user->gamertag }}</a>
@endforeach
```

/***** Edit***/

This works:

```html
{{ dd($message->user->gamertag) }}




// This does NOT
{{ $message->user->gamertag }}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the output of $message->user?

Comment: This is too weird LOL~

Comment: Ill try to figure it out in the morning tomorrow

Comment: @David could you show me your database schema, or chat and user table?

Comment: It might work properly and you have **another** variable causing the error. Try {{ @$messages->user->gamertag }} and see if the error persists. If it does, it's definitely not that variable which throws the exception.

Comment: got it working. Look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Everything was working here, its just in my chat table, I had inserted a message with no identified user, so user_id = 0, and it was throwing that error off. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use eager loading:

```
$messages = Chat::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->with('user')->get();
```

Comment: no, nothing. If I Die Dump the {{ $message->user->gamertag }}, I get the gamertag though

Comment: I didn't understand, you get nothing or you get gametag? If you get gametag with `dd($message->user->gametag)`, this means it's working.

Comment: It can't be true, if dd works, you should see result anyway. Maybe you don't see it because of `author` class? Can you check raw HTML output?